# Draw path traced by device using maps api v2

Tags: android, android-maps-v2

I am developing an android application to trace the device movement.I am able to get the current location but how can i draw the route with set of points collected during trip

Answer (score 2):

Define List for all points.

```
List< LatLng> points = new List< LatLng>();
```

//Add all points in list

```
points.add(new LatLng(lat1,lng1)); // POINT1

points.add(new LatLng(lat2,lng2)); // POINT2 and so on.
```

// then define PolylineOptions

```
PolylineOptions polylineOptions = new PolylineOptions();

polylineOptions.addAll(points);

Polyline route = googleMap.addPolyline(polylineOptions);
```

// for marker use MarkerOptions

Comment: List< LatLng> points = new List< LatLng>(); says cannot instatntiate type list<latlng>

Comment: ArrayList< LatLng> points = new ArrayList< LatLng>();    // change List to ArrayList

Answer (score -1):

Use something more reliable than drawing a route: **Markers**.

Check the google maps Sample application from the Android SDK, and take a look on the `MarkerDemoActivity.java` class.

Open eclipse:

**New Project->Android Sample Project->[YOUR_BUILD_TARGET]->maps [Google Play Service]**
This will give you a good idea about what you're trying to search for.

Here's an example of what you'll get:

[image]

Comment: I'll check and will get back to you later